# Importing UIViewController-classed file to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am using a GitHub project that will allow me to create a popup using a .xib file ([GitHub link 1](https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWPopup)). I am also using another project from GitHub that creates a side menu ([GitHub link 2](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)).

I want a popup to be shown when I tap on one of the buttons. The way the [second one is set up up](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu/blob/master/RESideMenuExample/RESideMenuExample/AppDelegate.m), however, requires me to add the code to the app delegate, and unfortunately, I am having issues with this.

This is the code that I am using for the popup:

```
SampleViewController *sampleViewController = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:samplePopupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

On the last line of code, I get this error message:

`No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish? You can't use "self" in this situation, because self is the app delegate, and presentViewController:animated:completion: is a method of UIViewController. Importing a view controller doesn't change that.

Comment: My apologies. I thought that if I made it generic enough, I would be able to get my answer, but at the same time, help others who would be experiencing similar issues. Looks like I made it too generic. I have updated the question as a result of it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing without knowing about those 2 links, but in general, you have to present a controller from whatever controller's view is currently on screen. So, you need to figure out what controller that is, and do your presentation from it.

Comment: Ah. I see. Ok then; I guess I'll have to figure out how to route the code for the second project into a ViewController. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you import the header for a view controller then you can create and display instances of that view controller in your app delegate.

Why not just try it?

Comment: I did try it, but I get an error message saying `No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'`. In fact, the example code IS the code that I'm using, but it doesn't seem to want to work.